# Is it possible to set all texture nodes in a node tree to a specific vector?

Tags: workflow, node-editor

Is there a way to automatically set selected nodes to use a specific vector input?

E.g. If you have a larger node setup with a lot of texture nodes, it can be a pain to go back through and connect each texture node's vector input to a texture coordinate node individually.

Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a *Reroute* node with the desired value and select it. Then, you can use this script.

```
# First, define some stuff
# mat: the material; tree: the node tree; nodes: the node list
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material Name'] # or index
tree = mat.node_tree
nodes = tree.nodes

# We'll find the source node and store it in src
src_socket = None
if nodes.active:
  if len(nodes.active.outputs) == 1:
    src_socket = nodes.active.outputs[0]

if src_socket is not None:                       # only work if node found
  for node in nodes:                             # check each node
    if node.type.startswith('TEX'):              # only operate on textures
      for input in node.inputs:                  # check each input
        if input.type == 'VECTOR':               # only operate on vectors
          tree.links.new(src_socket, input)      # set up the link
          break                                  # only do the first vector
else:                                            # fail if no valid select
  print('No single-output node selected')
```

Tested on Blender v2.69 r60995.

Comment: Instead of that first loop to assign src to the node, could you instead use src = nodes['CopyVector']? (using a try/except incase it doesn't exist)

Comment: @GregZaal Good point, thanks - but see my edit; this is easier anyway.

Comment: Well there's always a better solution isn't there ;)

Comment: There is a reference to an undefined variable `src` on line 13. I changed it to `src_socket` and it worked beautifully. Also, if anyone copy/pastes this they won't import `bpy`, you might want to add that. Thanks :)

Comment: @gandalf3 fix'd.